# Dependent template name argument substitution

Tags: c++, templates

I'm not sure how to explain this, so I'll give the code.

I'm trying to encode (for fun, also to help me understand template metaprogramming) Chuch numerals using C++ templates.

```
struct Z {
  static constexpr unsigned int n = 0;

  template<typename T>
  using replace = T;
};

template<typename T>
struct S {
  static constexpr unsigned int n = T::n + 1;

  template<typename U>
  // using replace = T::replace<U>;
  using replace = typename T::template replace<U>;
};
```

So, I tried `using replace = T::replace<U>`, which really didn't work, and I had no idea why (I was using GCC), <s>*and I'd appreciate if someone could explain why to me*</s> (see link below). When I tried compiling with Clang, it gave me a nice error message:

First, `use 'template' keyword to treat 'replace' as a dependent template name`, then `template argument for template type parameter must be a type; did you forget 'typename'?`...

Then I managed to make `using replace = typename T::template replace<U>` compile, this seems legal.

But what I actually needed was something like `S<T::replace<U>>`, which I found no way to make work.

I tried changing this to `T::replace<U>::succ` as well, and defining `succ` to be `S<Z>` on `Z` and `S<S<T>>` on `S`, but I couldn't make it work either...

Any ideas? :(

Comment: Have you read [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) as suggested in the Related bar (now linked)?

Comment: `S<T::replace<U>>` -> `S<typename T::template replace<U>>` ?

Comment: @dyp, I actually read that, but didn't manage to make it work anyways. And @Jarod42, `S<typename T::template replace<U>>` didn't compile, and that's what I didn't understand why.

Comment: Can you provide the context of how and where you use `S<typename T::template replace<U>>`? Preferably as an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @dyp, here: http://pastebin.com/swHVyzCB. I read some posts here on Stackoverflow, like the one you gave, but I still don't understand why `S<typename T::template replace<U>>` won't work there.

Comment: Problem is somewhere different: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8b1b778f3a2e4db You forgot the `replace` inside `I`

Comment: Oh God, you're right! My code would work if I did _2::replace<_2>, and would correctly sum to 4. I just got so confused by the errors the compiler gave me that forgot to check what I really wanted... embarassing. If you post an answer, I will accept it. And thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @PauloTorrens That shouldn't be embarrassing, understanding error messages related to templates can be hard ;)

Comment: @PauloTorrens: An alternative to dyp's solution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b146d7835ab5dd9f. So `S::replace` is removed by SFINAE.

Answer (score 1):

Church numerals have an arity of 2; they take a functor and a value and apply the functor `n` times to the value.  In metaprogramming, this can be expressed as a template with 2 template parameters, the first of which is a template template parameter:

```
struct Z {
  template<template<typename> class F, typename x>
  using replace = x;
};

template<typename T>
struct S {
  template<template<typename> class F, typename x>
  using replace = F<typename T::template replace<F, x>>;
};
```

We can test this with `F` as the successor function on `integral_constant`s (which aren't really values in the lambda calculus, but it doesn't care about that):

```
#include <type_traits>
template<typename N> using s = typename std::integral_constant<typename N::value_type, N::value + 1>;
static_assert(S<S<Z>>::replace<s, std::integral_constant<int, 2>>::value == 4, "arithmetic!");
```

If you want to curry `replace`, the syntax becomes somewhat more complex:

```
struct Z {
  template<template<typename> class F> struct replace {
    template<typename x> using apply = x;
  };
};

template<typename T>
struct S {
  template<template<typename> class F> struct replace {
    template<typename x> using apply = F<typename T::template replace<F>::template apply<x>>;
  };
};
```

Strictly speaking, by taking template template parameters we're introducing a distinction (between functors and values) that is absent in the untyped lambda calculus.  The way to fix that is to have our functors as typename parameters containing the application machinery:

```
struct Z {
  template<typename F> struct replace {
    template<typename x> using apply = x;
  };
};

template<typename T>
struct S {
  template<typename F> struct replace {
    template<typename x> using apply = typename F::template apply<typename T::template replace<F>::template apply<x>>;
  };
};
```

And the demonstration:

```
#include <type_traits>
struct s { template<typename N> using apply = typename std::integral_constant<typename N::value_type, N::value + 1>; };
static_assert(S<S<Z>>::replace<s>::template apply<std::integral_constant<int, 2>>::value == 4, "arithmetic!");
```

Comment: Though you are right, my doubt was really about why I couldn't use `S<typename T::template replace<U>>`, and @dyp just showed me that, although the error messages said something different, the error was because I was trying to use a class without replace<>. Thanks anyway, you got an interesting answer. :)